# Changing the bulb in an enclosure

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting, bulb

This particular light has been flickering. The base of the detachable part in the photo appears to be closed, so I can't get access to what's inside. Would anyone have experience changing or fixing this type of light? It is controlled by a Lutron dimmer.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**
I discovered the model I have is manufactured by Elite LED with number REL637-950L-DIMTR-120-27K/30K/35K/40K/50K-90-W-WH.
[https://www.amazon.com/Elite-REL637-950L-DIMTR-120-27K-50K-90-W-WH-Universal-Retrofit/dp/B08M9F3R8M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08M9F3R8M)

Comment: Are you able to read the small label?   There should be a brand or model there, for googling.  It might even show the lamp code, if it is a replaceable model.

Comment: @Criggie The small text there doesn't have a model number...it says something to the extent of "use only with suitable models". I'm trying to detach this fixture to see if there is anything else I can find.

Comment: Is it an LED? Many newer LED fixtures don't have a replaceable "bulb" like older incandescents do - instead you have to replace a more significant portion of the fixture because you're replacing the bulb _and_ the driver electronics. (Usually it's the electronics that die, not the LED itself.)

Comment: You don't even need to. This is an LED bulb conversion. Once you get it out as Alaska Man describes, you can take the whole shebang to the workbench, or to the lighting supply to get a comparable replacement.  Before you shop, please google "color temperature" and "CRI" - very important words.

Comment: @FreeMan & Harper: correct, it is an LED. I was able to detach the fixture and find the model (please see my update in the Question). Not being able to replace individual component seems to make this an expensive replacement... I am wondering if I need to get this exact replacement, or a generic one from Home Depot.

Comment: _In theory_ LEDs should last many, many thousands of hours more than an incandescent would have. Therefore the higher cost to replace half the fixture _is supposed to be_ offset by the lower daily cost of operation and the reduced frequency of replacement. Whether that truly works out is an exercise left to each individual consumer. (I've had (admittedly cheap) LED bulbs flicker and die in under a month. YMMV)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like an integrated LED can retrofit fixture (a close match for some of mine - I see the supply converter screwed into the original can socket) and you replace the whole thing - there is no removable bulb.

*If you enjoy tinkering the LEDs are probably fine, and the driver circuit is probably dying, but that's strictly "reuse LEDs for your low voltage projects" not "do a home replacement and return it to service at line voltage with unlisted parts and repairs" - for fixing the light in this location that's attached to mains voltage, just buy a new LED retrofit with all the proper listings so that you don't void your insurance...*

Comment: Right, I wouldn't want to (or know) how to fix it myself. But seeing this is not a cheap component, would you know if these are standard parts, or I need to order the exact model? I posted my model in the question above.

Comment: If your only issue with replacing this part is its $40 cost, I see $7 ones in the recommendations section of the very page you linked in the question.  No?  Otherwise just replace it with a $1 light bulb.  It won't look fantastic but ....

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Ecnerwal said in his answer:

It appears to me that the LED is a retrofit into an old can light housing. If this is the case then you do not need to get into the "base" as it is just 120v electrical supply wires.

The LED seems to have an adapter that is screwed in to a standard light bulb socket. The LED light itself is not serviceable, it contains the electronic circuitry that convert the 120v AC to DC current for the light emitting diode, and that is what is likely to be failing.

See if you can remove the LED  adapter from the socket and then you can take it to the store to find a compatible replacement.

Comment: Thanks Alaska Man. I found an exact replacement online (please see my update above), but I am wondering if I can replace this particular fixture with a generic, less expensive one - are these standard across all manufacturers?

Comment: They are generic, other than "it might look slightly different from others you have." I tend to buy whichever ones are on the "green energy rebate plan of the month" and if there is no plan that month, I tend to wait, as they are considierably cheaper that way. Your locl plans may vary. I've gotten them for between $5 and $15 that way, but list price when they are off the program is generally much more (2X-4X).